Qgis2threejs raster line
I am trying to get uploaded .jpg to vector type (line) ,after I categorized it, depth vise.
I am trying to get uploaded .jpg to vector type (Line) category , that i categorized based on a value. When I upload .jpg in "Symbol selector" for a specific sub-category, by double clicking "Symbol Selector " opens where I can select "Symbol layer type". In  "Symbol layer type" I select "Raster line" and upload .jpg, that goes fine.
However when i try to display  this in 3D, Qgis2threejs , it seems that this is not picked up but general "line" color to which  "Raster line" belongs to.
Is there a way to override this in Qgis2threejs  and to show like .jpg content , on a line, in 3D view of  Qgis2threejs ?
Rgds

